# Conversion from String to type Double is not valid when calculating min and max values

Tags: vb.net

I am receiving the following error with my code:

> Conversion from String to type Double is not valid

The program was running normally before with the correct output but I made few changes which were not valid and had to revert these, but it didn't work.

The program is made to find `min` and `max` values in a column of a text file.

If possible, please suggest a way to calculate `min` and `max` values for multiple columns in a text file separated with spaces (not consistent spaces) with somewhat similar approach as the following code.

```
Dim Textfile As String
Dim openDlg As New OpenFileDialog

If openDlg.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    openDlg.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)| *.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    openDlg.FilterIndex = 2
    openDlg.RestoreDirectory = True
    Textfile = openDlg.FileName


    Dim RECfile As New System.IO.StreamReader(Textfile)
    Dim textline As String

    Dim ln = 0
    Dim Max As Integer
    Max = 0
    Dim Min As Integer
    Min = 999999

    Do While RECfile.Peek() <> -1
        textline = RECfile.ReadLine()

        If textline > Max Then
            Max = textline
        End If

        If textline < Min Then
            Min = textline
        End If

        ln += 1

        Me.maxval.Text = Max
        Me.Minval.Text = Min

    Loop

    RECfile.Close()

End If
```

Sample data 1:

```
194787.5    194987.5          194787.5  194987.5
194987.5    195012.5          194987.5  195012.5
195012.5    2003999           195012.5  2003999
2003999     195037.5          2003999   195037.5
195037.5    195062.5          195037.5  195062.5
195062.5    195087.5          195062.5  195087.5
195087.5    195112.5          195087.5  195112.5
195112.5    195137.5          195112.5  495137.5
195137.5    195162.5          195137.5  195162.5
195162.5    194812.5          195162.5  19400012.5
        194837.5            194837.5
        194862.5            194862.5
        194887.5            194887.5
        194912.5            194912.5
        194937.5            194937.5
        12111               12111999
```

Sample date 2:

```
194987.5    195012.5          194987.5  195012.5
195012.5    2003999           195012.5  2003999
2003999     195037.5          2003999   195037.5
195037.5    195062.5          195037.5  195062.5
195062.5    195087.5          195062.5  195087.5
195087.5    195112.5          195087.5  195112.5
195112.5    195137.5          195112.5  495137.5
195137.5    195162.5          195137.5  195162.5
195162.5    194812.5          195162.5  19400012.5
        194837.5            194837.5
        194862.5            194862.5
        194887.5            194887.5
        194912.5            194912.5
        194937.5            194937.5
```

Edit:

These are screenshots of a warning that I am getting that I believe is linked with the code.

Screenshot 1:
[image]

Screenshot 2:

[image: designer form]

Comment: Do you want to examine only the lines which have ten columns? The line "12111 12111999" appears to have values unrelated to the other values. As you want the extremes for each *column*, you will have to read all the data in before finding the minima and maxima. Or did you really mean the minimum and maximum in each *line*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your sample data, `Integer` won't cut it. I suggest you change to using `Double` instead as *194787.5* won't parse to an `Integer`.

First and foremost turn **[Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx):**

> Restricts implicit data type conversions to only widening conversions, disallows late binding, and disallows implicit typing that results in an Object type.

Next I suggest you create a new temp variable and use [Double.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Converts the string representation of a number to its double-precision floating-point number equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion succeeded or failed.

A suggestion on your code would look something similar to this:

```
Dim temp As Double = 0

If Double.TryParse(textline, temp) Then

    If temp > Max Then
        Max = temp
    End If

    If temp < Min Then
        Min = temp
    End If

End If

Me.maxval.Text = Max.ToString()
Me.Minval.Text = Min.ToString()
```

Note the `.ToString()` on `Max` and `Min`. This is because they are `Doubles` and need to be converted to `String`.

Another suggestion I would like to make is to implement [Using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) to help with the disposing of objects.

Instead of:

```
Dim RECfile As New System.IO.StreamReader(Textfile)
```

You would have:

```
Using RECfile As New System.IO.StreamReader(Textfile)

   ...

End Using
```

You won't need to call `RECfile.Close()` either as the `Using` block will handle that.

I also can't see any use of the variable `ln` so remove it.

Lastly you state that the text file contains multiple columns which are separated with inconsistent spaces. I actually believe they are tab-separated values. That being said [Andrew Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1115360/andrew-morton) made a very good suggestion:

> ..split on {CChar(vbTab), " "c} just in case there isn't a tab between values (e.g. the file was hand-edited).

I suggest we use the [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
Dim textline As String() = RECfile.ReadLine().Split(New Char() {CChar(vbTab), " "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Overall your code would look something similar to this:

```
Using RECfile As New System.IO.StreamReader(Textfile)

    Dim Max As Double = Double.MinValue
    Dim Min As Double = Double.MaxValue

    Do While RECfile.Peek() <> -1
        Dim textline As String() = RECfile.ReadLine().Split(New Char() {CChar(vbTab), " "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

        For Each line In textline
            Dim temp As Double = 0

            If Double.TryParse(line.Trim(), temp) Then

                If temp > Max Then
                    Max = temp
                End If

                If temp < Min Then
                    Min = temp
                End If

            End If

            Me.maxval.Text = Max.ToString()
            Me.Minval.Text = Min.ToString()

        Next
    Loop

End Using
```

The output for me is:

```
Max = 19400012.5
Min = 12111
```

> Edited as per OP's request to get the minimum and maximum value for each column in the text file.

I've done my best to try and analyse the sample data and from what I can tell the values are tab-separated. If there is a missing value in a column then two tabs will be found next to each other. If there is a missing value in two adjoining columns then four tabs will be found next to each other.  To counter this I have replaced all occurrences of two tabs with one tab. This keeps the index solid.

First I've created two classes:

`ColumnValue`:

```
Public Class ColumnValue
    Public Key As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal id As Integer,
                   ByVal value As Double)

        _id = id
        _value = value

    End Sub

    Private _id As Integer
    Public ReadOnly Property ID As Integer
        Get
            Return _id
        End Get
    End Property

    Private _value As Double
    Public ReadOnly Property Value As Double
        Get
            Return _value
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

`ColumnValues`:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Public Class ColumnValues
    Inherits KeyedCollection(Of String, ColumnValue)

    Protected Overrides Function GetKeyForItem(ByVal item As ColumnValue) As String
        Return item.Key
    End Function

    Public Function GetMax(ByVal columnId As Integer) As Double

        Return (From c In Me
                Where c.ID = columnId
                Select c.Value).Max()

    End Function

    Public Function GetMin(ByVal columnId As Integer) As Double

        Return (From c In Me
                Where c.ID = columnId
                Select c.Value).Min()

    End Function

End Class
```

Note that on the `ColumnValues` class I have two functions to return the `Min` and `Max` based on the `columnId` passed using [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx).

This is the revised code I've put in place:

```
Dim myColumnValues As New ColumnValues

Using RECfile As New System.IO.StreamReader(Textfile)

    Do While RECfile.Peek() <> -1
        Dim textline As String() = RECfile.ReadLine().Replace(CChar(vbTab) & CChar(vbTab), vbTab).Split(New Char() {CChar(vbTab)})

        Dim columnId As Integer = 0

        For Each column In textline

            columnId += 1

            Dim temp As Double = 0

            If Double.TryParse(column.Trim(), temp) Then
                myColumnValues.Add(New ColumnValue(columnId, temp))
            End If

        Next
    Loop

    'Get a distinct list of column Ids to loop through
    Dim columnIds = (From c In myColumnValues
                     Order By c.ID
                     Select c.ID).Distinct()

    'Output the Max and Min for each column
    For Each c In columnIds

        Debug.WriteLine("Column: " & c.ToString() & " Max: " & myColumnValues.GetMax(c))
        Debug.WriteLine("Column: " & c.ToString() & " Min: " & myColumnValues.GetMin(c))

    Next

End Using
```

Note that I've had to revert to splitting on `vbTab` and not both tabs and spaces. By splitting on spaces as well it was causing to many issues with the indexes and the data just wasn't good enough to work with.

The output for *Sample Data 1* is:

```
Column: 1 Max: 2003999
Column: 1 Min: 194787.5

Column: 2 Max: 2003999
Column: 2 Min: 12111

Column: 3 Max: 2003999
Column: 3 Min: 194787.5

Column: 4 Max: 19400012.5
Column: 4 Min: 194837.5
```

Output for *Sample Data 2* is:

```
Column: 1 Max: 2003999
Column: 1 Min: 194987.5

Column: 2 Max: 2003999
Column: 2 Min: 194812.5

Column: 3 Max: 2003999
Column: 3 Min: 194987.5

Column: 4 Max: 19400012.5
Column: 4 Min: 194837.5
```

Edited as per OP's edit regarding screenshot errors.

I would create separate `Class` files for `ColumnValue` and `ColumnValues` like so:

`ColumnValue`:

[image]

`ColumnValues`:

[image]

Keep these separate from your `Form1` code.